# Oracle SQL join three tables

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, left-join

I have three Tables and I wanted the join query or relevant for the below mentioned results

```
 Types ( Table One)
 -------
 typeId
 -------
 square
 circle
 triangle


 Sets ( Table Two)
 ------
 id setValue setName
 ------------------
 1    one      setOne
 2    two      setTwo
 3    three    setThree


 Formation ( Table Three ) Types and sets are foreign keys to the other tables
 ---------
 id setValue  types     extra   notes
 --------------------------------------
 1     two     circle     5       xyz
 2     three   square     4       abc
```

I want to join this table and get result in such way ,  always i should get all the types displayed for the input gives as

if User choose **set** value as 'two' then result should be

```
 types      setValue        extra       notes
 --------------------------------------------
 square     null            null        null
 circle     two             5           xyz
 triangle   null            null        null
```

if user choose **type** value as 'square' then the result should be

```
  types     setValue        extra       notes
 --------------------------------------------
 square     three           4           abc
 circle     null            null        null
 triangle   null            null        null
```

if suppose user choose **set** value as 'rectangle' then the result should be

```
 types      setValue        extra       notes
--------------------------------------------
 square     null            null        null
 circle     null            null        null
 triangle   null            null        null
```

Looking forward for solution oracle 10g compatible code

Comment: I think this sounds like a great problem to solve.  A few notes about your question format however.  Its best to show work that you've tried rather than just say "do it for me".  I also think your title needs work.  This is more than just joining 3 tables, its about changing criteria but still getting back all records.. something along those lines would make the title more reflective.

Comment: @paqogomez I actually tried from my side and then only posted this query , But defintely I take your points going forward. Because it was very late night when I posted the query.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT F.types, F.setValue, F.extra, F.notes
FROM types t
LEFT JOIN Formation F
 on t.typeID = F.Types
 AND ((F.SetValue = 'YourSetInput')
  OR (F.Types = 'YourTypesInput'))
```

By using a left outer join we always keep all the types.  By putting limiting criteria on the join and not in a where clause we don't have to worry about accidently excluding the null values you want to see.

This however does have one draw back in that if both setvalue and types are keyed in both would return.  This may or may not be the desired result as the use case hasn't been covered.

So in recap

Return all the tables every time regardless of any other criteria.
Then return the criteria from formation that matches the selected inputs for type or set.